# Calculate padding for 3D CNN in Pytorch

Tags: neural-network, pytorch, conv-neural-network, padding

I'm currently trying to apply a 3D CNN to a set of images with the dimensions of 193 x 229 x 193 and would like to retain the same image dimensions through each convolutional layer (similar to tensorflow's `padding=SAME`). I know that the padding can be calculated as follow:

```
S=Stride
P=Padding
W=Width
K=Kernal size

P = ((S-1)*W-S+K)/2
```

Which yields a padding of 1 for the first layer:

```
P = ((1-1)*193-1+3)/2
P= 1.0
```

Although I also get a result of `1.0` for each of the subsequent layers. Anyone have any suggestions? Sorry, beginner here!

Reproducible example:

```
import torch
import torch.nn as nn

x = torch.randn(1, 1, 193, 229, 193)

padding = ((1-1)*96-1+3)/2
print(padding)

x = nn.Conv3d(in_channels=1, out_channels=8, kernel_size=3, padding=1)(x)
print("shape after conv1: " + str(x.shape))
x = nn.Conv3d(in_channels=8, out_channels=8, kernel_size=3,padding=1)(x)
x = nn.BatchNorm3d(8)(x) 
print("shape after conv2 + batch norm: " + str(x.shape))
x = nn.ReLU()(x)
print("shape after reLU:" + str(x.shape))
x = nn.MaxPool3d(kernel_size=2, stride=2)(x)
print("shape after max pool" + str(x.shape))
x = nn.Conv3d(in_channels=8, out_channels=16, kernel_size=3,padding=1)(x)
print("shape after conv3: " + str(x.shape))
x = nn.Conv3d(in_channels=16, out_channels=16, kernel_size=3,padding=1)(x)
print("shape after conv4: " + str(x.shape))
```

Current output:

```
shape after conv1: torch.Size([1, 8, 193, 229, 193])
shape after conv2 + batch norm: torch.Size([1, 8, 193, 229, 193])
shape after reLU:torch.Size([1, 8, 193, 229, 193])
shape after max pooltorch.Size([1, 8, 96, 114, 96])
shape after conv3: torch.Size([1, 16, 96, 114, 96])
shape after conv4: torch.Size([1, 16, 96, 114, 96])
```

Desired output:

```
shape after conv1: torch.Size([1, 8, 193, 229, 193])
shape after conv2 + batch norm: torch.Size([1, 8, 193, 229, 193])
...
shape after conv3: torch.Size([1, 16, 193, 229, 193])
shape after conv4: torch.Size([1, 16, 193, 229, 193])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**TLDR; your formula also applies to [`nn.MaxPool3d`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.MaxPool3d.html)**

You are using a max pool layer of kernel size `2` (implicitly `(2,2,2)`) with a stride of `2` (implicitly `(2,2,2)`). This means for every `2x2x2` block you're only getting a single value. In other words - as the name implies: only the maximum value from every `2x2x2` block is pooled to the output array.

That's why you're going from `(1, 8, 193, 229, 193)` to `(1, 8, 96, 114, 96)` (notice the division by `2`).

Of course, if you set `kernel_size=3` and `stride=1` on `nn.MaxPool3d`, you will preserve the shape of your blocks.

---

Let `#x` be the input shape, and `#w` the kernel shape. If we want the output to have the same size, then `#x = floor((#x + 2p - #w)/s + 1)` needs to be true. That's `2p = s(#x - 1) - #x + #w = #x(s - 1) + #w - s` (your formula)

Since `s = 2` and `#w = 2`, then `2p = #x` which is not possible.